# custom jquery plugin calls method from another js page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

i am trying to make custom jquery plugin but i am very beginner. i have simple html form

```
<form id="registerForm" action = "somepage" method="post" class="mb-sm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" for="fname">First Name* :</label> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter Owner's First Name" name="fname">
            <div class="alert alert-danger hidden mt-lg" id="fnameerrbox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

in my js folder i have js page called validation.js in which i have this coding

```
"use strict";
var errcontent;
function showerror(errbox, errcontent){
    if($(errbox).hasClass("hidden")){
    $(errbox).removeClass("hidden");
        $(errbox).html(errcontent);
    }
}
function hideerror(errbox, errcontent){
    if(!$(errbox).hasClass("hidden")){
    $(errbox).html(errcontent);
        $(errbox).addClass("hidden");
    }
}
(function ($){
$.fn.alphaNumeric = function(element, errbox){
var alphanumeric = /^[a-zA-Z 0-9.,]*$/;
    if(!alphanumeric.test(element)){
        errcontent = "Only alphabets, numbers, dot, comma are allowed";
        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
    }
    if(alphanumeric.test(element)){
        errcontent = "";
        hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

i have another js page named custom.js, in here i am taking values from input element. coding is here

```
"use strict";
var fname;
var errbox;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fname").keyup(function(){
        fname = $('#fname').val();
        errbox = $("#fnameerrbox");
        alphaNumeric(fname, errbox);
    });
});
```

when i run this i am getting error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: alphaNumeric is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement. (custom.js:8)
>       at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

i know i need to init this and my validation method "alphaNumeric" is not defined but i dont know how to init this. I am very new i will be very thankful if some one help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.fn.myFunc` is used when you want to do something like `$('#my-element').myFunc()` and the element is passed under `this` inside the myFunc. For what you are doing you don't need create a jQuery plugin because you are using a string instead of a dom element. But you could do something simple by removing the `.fn` like:

```
$.alphaNumeric = function(element, errbox){
var alphanumeric = /^[a-zA-Z 0-9.,]*$/;
    if(!alphanumeric.test(element)){
        errcontent = "Only alphabets, numbers, dot, comma are allowed";
        showerror(errbox, errcontent);
    }
    if(alphanumeric.test(element)){
        errcontent = "";
        hideerror(errbox, errcontent);
    }
}
```

And in your doc ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fname").keyup(function(){
        fname = $('#fname').val();
        errbox = $("#fnameerrbox");
        $.alphaNumeric(fname, errbox);
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry for bothering you. what is difference between these two like before and after removing fn

Comment: The ``$`` is a function and functions can be treated like objects too in js. By using ``$.fn.`` you are telling jQuery to add your function to $ as a function prototype. By doing $.func you're just adding func as an object key and value to $.